# Hadoop Streaming with a Sequencefile is very slow

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a hadoop streaming task with python. It worked but one of 32 mappers is very slow. I think the problem is some kind of data skew, but I don't where the problem is.

Here is hadoop task log, the first mapper is very very slow.

```
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000000      Records R/W=11327/11207 > map
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000001      Records R/W=786/783
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000002      Records R/W=854/851
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000003      Records R/W=850/847
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000004      Records R/W=812/809
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000005      Records R/W=802/799
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000006      Records R/W=854/851
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000007      Records R/W=822/819
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000008      Records R/W=888/885
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000009      Records R/W=1030/871
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000010      Records R/W=894/891
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000011      Records R/W=850/847
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000012      Records R/W=832/829
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000013      Records R/W=804/801
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000014      Records R/W=838/835
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000015      Records R/W=856/853
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000016      Records R/W=852/849
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000017      Records R/W=884/881
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000018      Records R/W=928/925
task_1520332877638_567306_m_000019      Records R/W=896/893
```

Job Command:
it's also very slow if enable speculative execution.

```
hadoop jar \
     /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0-EDH-0u1-SNAPSHOT-HA-SECURITY/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-EDH-0u1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
    -D stream.map.input=typedbytes \
    -D stream.map.output=typedbytes \
    -D stream.reduce.input=typedbytes \
    -D stream.reduce.output=text \
    -D mapred.job.queue.name=root.default \
    -D mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false \
    -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat \
    -mapper "sh map.sh" \
    -reducer "sh reduce.sh" \
    -input xxx \
    -output xxx ......
```

The input file is one sequencefile with a Text key and Binary value.

This input sequence file is generated by a MR task with only one reducer and a multipleoutput class.

```
-rw-rwx---+  3 lmt lmt      3.9 G 2018-05-24 19:53 inputfile
```

Any mistakes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: data skew is a problem of reducer, not mapper

Comment: and i guess it would be helpful if you posted your "map.sh". are you calling python inside?

Comment: yes. I call python in map.sh..  the first node has over 10000 lines, but only 800+ of other mappers. Other mappers stops but the first one is still running.. is this related to map.sh?

Comment: seems you're doing some key-based processing in your mapper, instead of moving that functionality to reducer, so you could be correct about skew issue. In any case, seeing your mapper would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason.

the value sizes in sequence files are not equal, some of them are very large but others quiet small -- caused data skew.